# Unity iOS make a file type launch your app and get Path of file

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, android-intent

I am creating an iOS app in Unity, which handles .CSV files.

Which `info.plist` property do I need to add to mark CSV files as supported by my app? (So upon touching CSV files my app would launch)

Also, I need the path only for the CSV file that launches my app.

I am using this the `OnAppliationFocus()` method, but how do I get the path of the file that launched my app?

Answer (score 0):

This can only be a partial answer, but you would use `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs ();` to get the command line properties which would include the path of the file that launches your app.

Comment: to quickly test it, I ran it on android, but it doesn't work. Does it only work on iOS?